# my Codeigniter form with ajax return all page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

In my project I user ajax to process form. Now i want to get Post data to process. I use Javascript when Jquery is not allowed. But Ajax return whole page, how can I fix that.

My controller :

```
class Form extends Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->model('Form_model');
    }

    function index() {
       $this->loadForm();

    }

    function loadForm() {
        $this->load->view('form_view');
    }

    function ajax_add_form_content() {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "XMLHttpRequest") {
            echo $_POST['fullname'] . '+' . $_POST['subject'];
        } else {
            echo '0';
        }
    }

}
```

And my view :

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Form view</title>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">


        function ajax_post(){

            var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var url = "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/form/ajax_add_form_content'?>";
            var fn = document.getElementById("txtFullName").value;
            var ln = document.getElementById("txtSubject").value;
            var vars = "fullname="+fn+"&subject="+ln;
            hr.open("POST", url, true);

            hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                    var return_data = hr.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
                }
            }

            hr.send(vars); 
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
            return false;
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="form">
        <span id='status' ></span>
        <form class="form" method="post">
            <p class="formName">contact</p>
            <p class="formDesc">contact us</p>
            <div class="form_elements">
                <div class="textField">
                    <label>Full name</label>
                    <input id="txtFullName" class="inputText required" type="text" maxlength="255" size="28" name="txtFullName">


                </div>

                <div class="textField">
                    <label>Subject</label>
                    <input id="txtSubject" class="inputText required" type="text" maxlength="255" size="28" name="txtSubject">


                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form_submit">
                <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Send" name="btnSubmit" onClick="javascript:ajax_post();">
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id='display'>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: What do you get as the response? Whole page means what?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

in your controller

```
function ajax_add_form_content() {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "XMLHttpRequest") {
            echo $_POST['fullname'] . '+' . $_POST['subject'];
        } else {
            echo '0';
        }
  exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend You to use ie Chrome inspector to see whether You send request to the proper url.

Additionally instead of using `$_SERVER` variables You can use method from CI library `$this->input->is_ajax_request()`.